# I am getting a stack overflow, and i'm not too sure how

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, x86-64, masm

Ok so this is happening when I recursively call my factorial procedure from my combination. It throws the exception right on the factorial procedure. I have included all of my code but the problem has to do with the stack and my factorial procedure. It is when I attempt to push rax for some reason. I cannot figure out why that is the case. Here is my code:

```
INCLUDELIB libcmt.lib
INCLUDELIB legacy_stdio_definitions.lib

EXTERN printf:PROC
EXTERN scanf:PROC
.DATA
    promt BYTE "1permutation..2)combination ",0
    inFmt BYTE "%d",0
    disp BYTE "You entered %d", 10, 0
    num QWORD ?
    fct_num QWORD ?
    num2 REAL8 1.5
    factpromt BYTE "What number do you want to find the factorial of?",0
    factFmt BYTE "%d",0
    factNum BYTE "The result is = %d", 10, 0
    n   QWORD   ?
    r   QWORD   ?
    result  QWORD   ?
    answer  QWORD   ?
    divisor QWORD   ?

   .CODE
   main PROC
 push   divisor         ;ebp+20
 push   n              ;ebp+16
 push   r              ;ebp+12
 push   result          ;ebp+8
 sub    rsp, 24
 lea    rcx, promt      ;for x64
 call   printf
 lea    rdx, num        ;for x64
 lea    rcx, inFmt      ;for x64
 call   scanf
 mov    rdx, num
 cmp    rdx, 2
 je     run_comb
 jmp    run_perm
 run_perm:
    call permutation
 run_comb:
    call combination
 ;lea   rcx, disp
 ;call  printf
 add    rsp, 24
 mov    eax,0
 ret
 main ENDP



factorial PROC 

mov     rax,qword ptr [rsp+8]
cmp     rax,1
jle     endRecursive
dec     rax
push    rax;throws exception here
call    factorial
mov     rsi,qword ptr [rsp+8]
mul     rsi
endRecursive:
    ret 8



factorial ENDP

permutation PROC 

mov ecx, 5
mov eax, ecx

ret
permutation ENDP

combination PROC 

push    rbp
mov     rbp,rsp

mov     rax, [rbp+32]   ;find (n-r)!
sub     rax, [rbp+24]
mov     rbx, rax
push    rbx
call    factorial
mov     rdx,[rbp+40]    ;move (n-r)! into result
mov     [rdx],rax

mov     rbx, [rbp+24]        ;find r!
push    rbx
call    factorial


mov     rdx,[rbp+40]
mov     rbx, [rdx]
mul     rbx         ;r!*(n-r)!, store product in eax
mov     rbx, [rbp+40]
mov     [rbx], rax          ;store product in divisor variable

mov     rbx, [rbp+32]   ;find n!
push    rbx
call    factorial
mov     rdx,[rbp+40]            
mov     rbx,[rdx]           ;move value of divisor into ebx

mov     rdx, 0
div     rbx         ;divide n! by divisor (r!*(n-r)!)
mov     rbx, [rbp+16]
mov     [rbx],rax                 ;move quotient into result

pop     rbp
ret     32
combination ENDP

END
```

Comment: have you tried to run this through a debugger like visual studio? should tell you what instruction things are failing on. by looking at registers/stack/memory you should be able to debug this.

Comment: The "variables" n, r, divisor ... seem not to be initialized. If they contain a random value you might calculate some very large value (such as `1000000000!`). Because each recursive call requires 16 bytes of stack that will fail if the stack is smaller than 16 times the number you want to calculate.